# need help with resolv.conf

Tags: domain-name-system, freebsd

my freebsd server runs a nameserver. the nameserver has information about a single domain. a common, I think, setup for a dedicated server. I also have an upstream nameserver that i would like to forward all requests to that do not concern the domain that I do not serve. below is my /etc/resolv.conf is it correct? I am new to this, and I am not a sysadmin. it seems to work and the names that i do not host get resolved but one thing confuses me that nslookup gives "Non-authoritative answer:" warning:

```
$ nslookup yahoo.com
Server:         127.0.0.1
Address:        127.0.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   yahoo.com
Address: 69.147.125.65
Name:   yahoo.com
Address: 72.30.2.43
Name:   yahoo.com
Address: 98.137.149.56
Name:   yahoo.com
Address: 209.191.122.70
Name:   yahoo.com
Address: 67.195.160.76
```

please advise.

Thanks
Konstantin

```
search bluecherrymedia.com
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 76.73.0.2
```

Comment: Is your question about resolv.conf or is it about the nameserver?

Comment: it is about whether what i want to achieve is done the way it should be done? how would an experienced sysadmin do it? I suspect that since nslookup says that the second server is non-authoritative, i might have misconfigured my authoritative server for my domain name.

Comment: There is no way to do it in resolv.conf. You have to configure your dns server to resolve everything

Comment: It's... not even looking at the second server.

Comment: thank you, how could you tell that it is not looking at the second server? how do i set up my DNS server to resolve everything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Non-authoritative answer" just means that the response did not come from a nameserver which was authoritative (owner) for the hostname. In this case, not a yahoo.com nameserver.

As long as DNS resolution is otherwise working, you should be fine.

Comment: thank you. I am confused about the fact that if i remove the second nameserver line from resolv.conf name resolution still works, i do not know why... and since if resolv.conf does not have any nameserver directives, BIND assumes localserver, i could remove both lines and have just the "search" directive, correct?

Comment: Your system is set to look up domains using localhost. It's hitting your local DNS server for the queries. Chances are, everything is setup fine if it's actually working. Your DNS will hit the Internet and look for the domain if it doesn't know it.

Comment: The function of hostname resolution and the BIND service are essentially disparate. Resolution occurs via your computer's resolver (and in Unix typically uses /etc/resolv.conf). BIND is a DNS server that allows you to provide DNS service. If your server is running a nameserver such as BIND on 127.0.0.1, it will use that if the entry is in resolv.conf. Does that help?

Comment: my understanding is that when I type "nslookup google.com" a request is sent to my nameserver first, correct? since it does not know the address of google.com what happens next? what nameserver is queried then? who does it?

Comment: This should answer your question [howstuffworks - dns](http://www.howstuffworks.com/dns.htm)